# How does my Golf Club UML Class Diagram look?

Tags: class, oop, uml, class-diagram

I'm prepping for an interview in which I need to model a real life scenario in UML. I'm trying to get some practice in. I've created the following diagram of a Golf Club and I'm wondering if you I could get some feedback on any *major* flaws.

Any obvious mistakes?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nlDw.jpg

Are my relationships right, I am unsure when to use Association or composition.

Comment: Please ask a specific question. Further: I won't sign up for a picture service to see your picture. So in short I can answer your question: Invisible.

Comment: I've added a new public link. Could you take a look?

Comment: Well, it looks ok.

Comment: Thanks, So no "major" mistakes ? any minor items you would change?

Comment: As said: looks fine. Since I don't know the domain I can't tell if it's semantically correct or not.

Comment: thank you very much for feedback.

Comment: If you were one of my student, I would say some remarks:-

Answer (score 0):

If you were one of my students, I would say some remarks (I hope that will help you to prepare your interview):

- this is a model for analyze not for implementation (this is not an issue but, for me, it has to be said)
- is it sure that a course will never get more than 18 holes ?, can't you have hole without course ? (for practice ?)
- a club must have one course and one course only, is it normal ?
- you choose to show some attributes and methods why these ones ? (I feel that when you implement the model you will need more attributes and methods)
- it seems to model persistent data what's about others classes ?

About association and composition, there are a lot's of questions on stackoverflow, see for example : [Composition in UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397555/composition-in-uml/42397790#42397790)